# How to group similar data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an output like this:

```
foldername    setname           testname           step     stepdescription    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name1.0       setname 1.1.1     testname1          step1       stpdes5         
name2.1       setname 1.0.0     testname2          step1       asdf5           
name2.1       setname 1.0.0     testname2          step2       ;lkj10          
name2.1       setname 1.0.0     testname2          step3       aaaaaa10        
name3         setname 1.2.1     testname3          step1       nnnn10
```

I want the output in the below way:

```
foldername    setname           testname           step     stepdescription    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
name1.0       setname 1.1.1     testname1          step1       stpdes5         
name2.1       setname 1.0.0     testname2          step1       asdf5           
                                                   step2       lkj10          
                                                   step3       aaaaaa10        
name3         setname 1.2.1     testname3          step1       nnnn10
```

Comment: You appear to want to return a result set that has a varying number of columns in each row. This is not something that is typically done in SQL Server. Usually you would return the entire result set and then format as needed on your business or display layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with ROW_NUMBER

```
SELECT case when seq >1 THEN '' ELSE foldername END as foldername,
       case when seq >1 THEN '' ELSE setname END as setname,
       case when seq >1 THEN '' ELSE testname END as testname,
       step,
       stepdescription
FROM
(
SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY foldername, setname, testname order by (select NULL) ) as seq
FROM Table1
) T
```

Comment: Would you do this in a production environment?

Comment: Thanks for the query but it gives me a incorrect syntax error ''

Comment: No I am not doing this on a production environment

Comment: @bharadwaj, what is the error, i tried it with test data

Comment: @Rajesh the error I am getting is incorrect syntax error ''

Comment: @bharadwaj, is table name and column names exactly same as described in the post, you can check SQL fiddle.

Comment: @Rajesh No not exactly... I just posted an example.. do you want me to paste the exact query and the results that I see and what I want?

Comment: @bharadwaj, if you can create it in sqlfiddle, it would be easier.